# What convention maps poco properties to columns automatically? And how can I disable that auto-mapping?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have both existing poco models and an existing database that I would like to use with EF 6. However many of my models have properties that don't map to columns in the database. When EF sends a select statement to sql it asks for those properties like they are columns, but since the columns don't exist EF ends up throwing an "Invalid column name" exception.

Is there a convention in EF 6 that makes all poco properties be treated as if they are column types? If so, which convention is responsible for this? If not, what other mechanism is responsible for this behavior, and how can I disable it?

Ideally I'd like my implementation to only treat a poco property as a column in the db if I explicitly map it in a EntityTypeConfiguration like so:

```
public class MyPocoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Authorization>
{
    public MyPocoMap()
    {
        this.Property(t => t.MyPropName).HasColumnName("MyColumnName");
    }
}
```

And not have to do this for all the properties I **don't** want EF to map:

```
this.Ignore(t => t.MyPropName);
```

Here's an example of how I am doing my mapping. I'd like to find a way to disable the mapping of the NotColumn1 and NotColumn2 properties without explicitly using the fluent api to ignore each of those properties.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    public MyContext()
        : base("Name=MyContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyModelMap());
    }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public int CustomId { get; set; }
    public string MyColumn1 { get; set; }
    public string MyColumn2 { get; set; }
    public string NotColumn1 { get; set; }
    public string NotColumn2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyModelMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyModel>
{
    public MyModelMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("MyTable");
        this.HasKey(t => t.CustomId);
        this.Property(t => t.MyColumn1).HasColumnName("Column1Name");
        this.Property(t => t.MyColumn2).HasColumnName("Column2Name");
        this.Ignore(t => t.NotColumn1);
        this.Ignore(t => t.NotColumn2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Code, Model or Database First?

Comment: @abatishchev I'm using code first and mostly mapping everything by hand... though I'm generating a lot of the mapping code using the EF Powertools Beta 4 "reverse engineer code first" tool outside of my solution and then manually bringing in what I need for each poco/poco-mapping.

Comment: @rafe did yo usolve this?

Comment: Wondering if you have any update on this.  I understand that this is a huge hassle when you're doing multi-versioning on your database and want to precisely control when to map certain properties (because some database versions may not have them or have different columns).  However, I have not found which particular convention to remove...

Answer (score 3):

In `EF6` you can use following custom convention code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
    modelBuilder.Properties() 
                .Where(p => p.Name == "SomePropertyName") 
                .Configure(p => p.Ignore()); 
}
```

You can find more custom code conversations for `EF6`at this [address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx)

Comment: So just remove the '.Where(p => p.Name == "SomePropertyName")' to get the specific answer to this question! It seems like an unusual way to work though don't you think?

Comment: @Colin, that would be the answer if rather than removing the Where clause, you replaced it with something like .Where(p=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ColumnName)). But there is no public access to the internal state that says if a column name has been set (via .HasColumnName()) that I could find. I tried using reflection to get the internal ColumnName property, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get to it... it's defined on an object that gets passed around via a delegate. But anyway, without a where clause like that every property on every entity will be ignored.

Comment: @Rafe I thought you wanted every property on every entity to be ignored by default? What happens if you put this line first, to set the default and then write `this.Property(t => t.MyPropName).HasColumnName("MyColumnName");` subsequently? Code conventions work on a last wins basis

Comment: @Colin I will try that, but I think .HasColumnName() and .Ignore() work independently internally. I think "last wins" only applies to configuration mappings using the same operation, for instance if there were two calls to .HasColumnName(), the second one would "win".

Comment: @Rafe maybe you should request `.NoticeMeAgain()` method... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The [**Code First Data Annotation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj591583.aspx) `[NotMapped]` from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;` should suffice.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int CustomId { get; set; }
    public string MyColumn1 { get; set; }
    public string MyColumn2 { get; set; }
    [Not Mapped]
    public string NotColumn1 { get; set; }
    [Not Mapped]
    public string NotColumn2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that is also another option that would prevent the auto-mapping. I'm looking for a way to disable the auto-mapping convention so that you don't have to "unmap" for each column like this by either using an annotation or using the fluent api's .Ignore(). But thanks for posting this - it's great to have as an answer for completeness!